# Unable to install UWP side-loading builds

Tags: uwp, msix

Using Visual Studio 15.9.4, we are creating a UWP side-loading package. We are getting the new msix/msixbundle outputs.

1. There is no association in windows for right-clicking and installing this extension (msix/msixbundle).
2. When attempting to run the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 script, we are getting "Error: The package or bundle is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted."
3. This has just started happening and we are using the same official UWP store associated cert as used in previously successful side-loading builds.

Does anyone have any inputs on how to get UWP side-loading builds to work again?

Answer (score 2):

After you successfully package the app with visual Studio, there will be a security certificate file in the form of .cer under the *_Test folder.You need to install the security certificate file before sideload your app.I often follow these steps to install the certificate: double click .cer file > choose Install certificate > choose Local machine > press the Browse button >choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities(or Trusted people)
[image]

We could run the .ps1 with PowerShell (if the device is the previous versions of Windows, you could refer the details on the document: [Sideload your app on previous versions of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-on-previous-versions-of-windows)) or double click the appxbundle/msixbundle to install the app on the local device.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the description above. We are installing the certificate as you described above, before we run the powershell script. It is at that point that we get the error message. Also, just to be complete: on my version of Windows (Windows 10 Pro, Build 1803, 17134.471), double-clicking will not install an msix or msixbundle.  Finally, I cannot find a way to force Visual Studio to go back to producing appx or appxbundle builds.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here from a google search, I was able to resolve a similar issue by installing the msixbundle via Powershell...

```
Add-AppPackage -path “C:\Caphyon\MyBundle.msixbundle”
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi! A doubt ... I'm trying to do an installation that way, whoever runs the command is a service logged with the local system user. Ai gives that this user does not have permission. Is it possible to release the permission for this user?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am now experiencing stable behavior after upgrading my Windows OS to Version: 1809; Build: 17763.194.

Specifically:

1. I am able to install by double-clicking the msix/msixbundle from File Explorer.
2. I am able to run the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 with PowerShell successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue because there are several steps to side-loading correctly. To that end I have wrapped it all up in an OpenSource batch file, which self elevates UAC so that it can enable dev mode/side loading, register the certificate file and then install the msixbundle or similar. It will then prompt the user if they want to create a desktop shortcut and lastly to launch the app after install.

The batch file can be found here, in a handy gist - https://gist.github.com/CartBlanche/cc135d46944818864d9d468916c982cd

Comment: So, this allows a silent install without prompting for the cert, right? I'm sorry if that's a stupid question, but I've never made a desktop app and the desktop support guy is trying to install this for multiple users and can't.

Comment: @Jamie It isn't a totally silent install as it prompts for things like creating a desktop Icon, but as the code is all there, you can customise it to your needs and see if it does what you need. If you are trying to install on a company set of computers, they may have it locked down more, than home users. If that is the case they that lock down needs to be lifted before the install, then put back in afterwards. Maybe DM me the error they are getting?